# Proving that $f(x) = x^2 + c$ will not converge for $c = 1/4$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I really struggle to fully prove the following: I've got on a function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ continuous at $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ We then have sequence $ (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_1 = x$ and $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ for $n>1 $.

Then, if $f(y) = y^2 + constant:c$, sequence would not converge for any value $x,$ when $c > 1/4$

I tried to write it down piece by piece, and so first showing for 1/4

$x_1 = y^2 + 1/4$
$x_2 = (y^2 + 1/4)^ 2 + 1/4$
$x_3 = ((y^2 + 1/4)^ 2 + 1/4)^ 2 + 1/4$
$x_4 = (((y^2 + 1/4)^ 2 + 1/4)^ 2 + 1/4)^ 2 + 1/4$
Then I believe as n goes to infinity we can write
$x_n = (x^n + 1/4)^{2n} + 1/4^n + 1/4$

Using test for radius of convergence I get
$ [(x^{n+1} + 1/4)^{2n+1} + 1/4^{n+1} + 1/4] / [(x^n + 1/4)^{2n} + 1/4^n + 1/4] $
Then the solution for that is $|4x^2 + 1|$ so seems that is not convergent for any x? I must have done something wrong or used the wrong technique or assumption for that, if anyone can suggest what I should do instead I would really appreciate

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;x_n - x_{n-1} = x_{n-1}^2 - x_{n-1} + c = \left(x_{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 + c - \dfrac{1}{4} \ge c - \dfrac{1}{4} \gt 0\,$.

Comment: Why would you show first for $c=1/4? $ Is it true that $1/4>1/4?$

Comment: And when $c=1/4,$ you can get $f(1/2)=1/2,$ so $f(x_n)$ converges for at least one $x,$ name $x=1/2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I wanted to firstly show the case when it converges, to then prove it by contradiction with c>1/4, but I failed the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose it converges to $x$ Then, by continuity, we get $x=x^{2}+c$. So $(x-\frac 1  2)^{2}=\frac  1 4 -c<0$. This is a contradiction since $(x-\frac 1  2)^{2} \geq 0$.